# openshift phpmyadmin redirect loop

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, openshift

I'm using openshift to deploy a hobby project however phpmyadmin does not open when i click on the icon. instead chrome waits a long time and then gives a 'redirect loop' error. does anybody know a workaround for this issue? I just need to set up my database tables.

Comment: You were able to use it before? Have you tried to restart the application? Maybe could be a browser cache issue, try to clear browsing data.

Comment: no i was never able to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this happen before when my application idled. Just visit your app in a web browser at 'yourapp-yournamespace.rhcloud.com' to unidle your application and then try the PHPMyAdmin link again.